# Installing and setting up logstash

Tags: mongodb, parsing, etl, logstash

I need to use Logstash to parse data from custom log files (generated from the our application). I have a tomcat server and mongodb. After going through the documentation online, I'm still unclear as to how to use the different input sources. There is a community based mongoDB database, but I'm unclear as to how use it.

How can I set up/ where should I start to begin using logstash parse logs from files?

Comment: Your question should be on server fault. But you can have a look to grok http://logstash.net/docs/1.0.17/filters/grok. I never used it but heard about it.

Comment: Please visit to logstash tutorial.